# Check number of Unread messages in Table?

Tags: c#, sql, database, razor, webmatrix

I have done this before but this time it's just not working.

All I am trying to do is COUNT() the number of unread messages there are in a table.

Table def:

```
UserId(int), From(int), Type(nvarchar), Message(nvarchar), Read(bit)
```

The Read and `UserId` columns are what I"m trying to check against. I have tried the following:

```
 database.QuerySingle("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfNotifications FROM Notifications WHERE UserId = @0 AND Read = CONVERT(bit,0)", userid);
```

I have also tried *many* other versions but it's always the same result. I always get the following error:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Read'.  Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'Read'.

What I am trying to do, is this:
*"GET NUMBER OF UNREAD MESSAGES IN NOTIFICATIONSTABLE WHERE USERID = @0 AND READ = FALSE"*

Any help at all is appreciated!

Thank you

## UPDATED

Below is full code of the helper I am experiencing problems with. Now that I have got the error fixed up, I don't know why it's not displaying the "You have new notifications message" when i sign in - there are 4 rows in the corresponding table.

```
@helper RetrievePhotoWithName(int userid)
{
    var database = Database.Open("DUDE");
    var name = database.QuerySingle("select FirstName, LastName, ProfilePicture from UserProfile where UserId = @0", userid);
    var notifications =  database.QuerySingle("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfNotifications FROM Notifications WHERE UserId = @0 AND [Read] = @1", userid, false);

    var DisplayName = "";
    if(notifications["NumberOfNotifications"] < 1)
    {
        DisplayName = name["FirstName"] + " " + name["LastName"];
    }
    else
    {
        DisplayName = name["FirstName"] + ", you have " + notifications["NumberOfNotifications"] + " new messages.";
    }
    <a href="@Href("~/Home")" title="My Account"><img src="@Href("~/Shared/Assets/Images/" + name["ProfilePicture"] + ".png")" id="MiniProfilePicture" />&nbsp;@DisplayName</a>

    database.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

try to put square brackets surrounding the `read` ===>  `[Read]`

Comment: read is a keyword so you have to put [] to tell the SQL that this is a column name not a keyword ...

Comment: Omg, I totally overlooked that. Thank you! But it still doesn't work. (But atleast there are no errors now.) I have updated my question with full (not muh) code. Please have a bit of a look if you can :)

Comment: is the returned value 'notifications' integer ?

Comment: Yep. Should be. But i have no way of seeing that I know of because when I try to output the value of notifications, nothing appears.

Comment: When it enters the iff statement, it always displays just the name of the person who is signed in, which only happens if there are no unread notifications - but there are.

Comment: Sir, do you know how to debug your code?
if yes {just please tell me if of its exact value and datatype }:
if no {tell me so i can provide you with the instructions}

Comment: The data type, as stated *in my question* is _bit_ :-) Thank you, @user1225246

Answer (score 1):

Your error states that `READ` is a keyword.  It's interpretting that a a command, or such like, and not a field name.

Indifferent versions of SQL you can enclose field names in different markers to prevent this confusion.  For example SQL Server would use `[Read]`, MySQL uses backticks such as `` `Read` ``.

Comment: Thank you @Dems. That is so weird, because I've never had to enclose Boolean column names in anything before. I dunno.. But thanks :)

Comment: @shane - It's not that the field is `BOOLEAN` it's that you've chosen a field name that means something in SQL. Imagine the confusion if you had a table called `SELECT` with a single field called `FROM`. You'd have `SELECT FROM FROM SELECT`. But in SQL Server you could do `SELECT [FROM] FROM [SELECT]`.  My *personal* recommendation is just to avoid using table and field names that are reserved keywords.